# Created a site with one HTML and multiple JS files that load when links are clicked in nav-how do I set URLS & prevent clearing in refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created a resume-type website with one HTML file and multiple JavaScript files that load the data when the  links are clicked in the navigation panel.  How do I set URLs for each page & prevent clearing/redirecting back to the homepage when the page is refreshed?  I am working locally and have uploaded my files to a web server as well and not too sure how to solve this.

Currently, when working locally (for example):
Homepage is -> D:/websitefolder/mywebsite.html
Clicking 'About Me' will change URL to -> D:/websitefolder/mywebsite.html#/about-me/

When refresh (or F5) is pushed, the location remains as [ D:/websitefolder/mywebsite.html#/about-me/ ], because it clears the JavaScript and displays the original page before any JavaScript functions are called.

Currently, I have my navigation set as:

```
<div class="sideNav">
    <a href="#/about-me/" onclick="aboutMe()">About Me</a><br>
    <a href="#/education/" onclick="education()">Education</a><br>
    <a href="#/projects/" onclick="proj()">Projects</a><br>
    <a href="#/contact/" onclick="contact()">Contact</a><br>
</div>
```

I know things work a bit differently on a web server, but not sure what approach to take.  How can I set the URLs for each link and when refresh page occurs, stays with the same JavaScript data loaded?  Should I have created multiple html files instead?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: On page load, read the hash and call the function that corresponds to it.

Comment: here is a (silly) working example based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/o47Lcnum/